# Adding a module in nxweb

Tags: c, webserver, nxweb

I want to give nxweb a try. So I successfully got it installed. Unfortunately the documentation is non-existant. After digging around in the code and the INSTALL notes I figured that I had to place my `C` file in the modules subdirectory and recompile the main executable via:

```
gcc -O2 -g main.c modules/*.c -o mynxweb `pkg-config --cflags --libs nxweb`
```

As this didn't work out I found some code in the `main.c` which seems to handle the registration of modules. So I added:

```
NXWEB_HANDLER_SETUP(my_click, "/click", click, .priority=1000);
```

and recompiled. It compiles just fine. But I can't find a `click.o` (my source file is called `click.c`) in the `src/bin` directory. The info messages don't mention my module either. So I'm at a loss as to what I am missing.

Maybe we can start a little nxweb noob docu on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the procedure is the following:

1. Build and install nxweb from [source](https://bitbucket.org/yarosla/nxweb/downloads). Follow instructions from INSTALL file. This shall install nxweb library.
2. Write your module. Take `bin/modules/hello.c` as example. Make sure you have `NXWEB_DEFINE_HANDLER(my_unique_handler_name, ...)` in it.
3. Build nxweb executable using provided `main.c` and your module, link it to nxweb library:

   `` gcc -O2 -g main.c my_module.c -o mynxweb `pkg-config --cflags --libs nxweb` ``
4. Configure `routing` table in nxweb_config.json by specifying URL prefix that should invoke your handler:

   `{ "prefix":"/my_handler_url", "handler":"my_unique_handler_name" },`
5. Launch/restart nxweb.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

You also have to add your module name and the routing path to `nxweb_config.json`.

For example:

```
{ // see modules/click.c
  "prefix":"/click", "handler":"click"
},
```